# ImportError: cannot import name 'experimental_functions_run_eagerly' from 'tensorflow.python.eager.def_function'

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

When I try to install tensorflow in jupyter notebook I get the following error:

```
ImportError: cannot import name 'experimental_functions_run_eagerly' from 'tensorflow.python.eager.def_function'
```

I have to add that I have just installed tensorflow-gpu.
Before it worked fine.
Also I have installed CUDA and CUDNN.

Comment: I see that it changes the method name, please add program versions.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/experimental_run_functions_eagerly

Comment: Which program versions? Of tensorflow or cuda?

Comment: Hi @AniaSikora, Jupyter Notebook installs the latest version of TensorFlow, which is 2.11. TensorFlow 2.10 was the last TensorFlow release that supported GPU on native-Windows. Starting with TensorFlow 2.11, you will need to install TensorFlow in WSL2. Kindly follow the instructions from [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) on how to install Tensorflow. Please specify the platform(windows, macos) for better assistance. Thank you!